# Detect response of consumer not match with requester expected

Tags: masstransit

we're using masstransit to deliver our message between multiple service. We're facing issue that a lot of consumer have wrong return type and lead to Message not consumed error. I want to log expected return type and what consumer response. Are there any convinion way to do this like in filter, middleware or interceptor?

Expected: Able to log all of the Consumer have wrong return type without a lot of code changes